# Convert Mobile Ads method to a Lambda expression. How could I do that?

Tags: java, android, lambda, ads

First of all, my code is working, so this is more like a "best practice" kind of question.

I am working with [Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#java), using the following code with MobileAds.initialize method:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Android Studio is giving me the following warning:

`Anonymous new OnInitializationCompleteListener() can be replaced with lambda`

I checked out about lambda expressions [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp)

But I am not sure how, if I should do this conversion, and what would be the benefits of it (just more readability?)

If someone could enlight me I will be thankful.

Comment: if you are using android studio put your cursor on where you getting that warning and press `alt + enter` or if you see a **Light bulb** click there and you will get options to convert to `lambda expresion`

Comment: or you can write this code - ```MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> { // your code here }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically to solve `Warnings` in android developing and If you are using `Android Studio` you can solve those mistakes pretty easily by `Ide` itself!

Like you are getting warning -

`Anonymous new OnInitializationCompleteListener() can be replaced with lambda`

you can easily solve by pressing `alt + enter` or clicking a **light bulb** and then you will get lot of option to fix those warnings

In your problem you can convert it like this -

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> { 
   // your code here 
});
```

for example you can see this image by **Light Bulb or Alt + Enter** while putting cursor in the grey code line.

[image]